# What's the formal of C++ const reference (not reference to const, but const reference)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, template-aliases

Given

```
template< class Type >
void constref( Type const ) {}

void constref_call() { double x; constref<double&>( x ); }      // OK

template< class Type >
using reference = Type&;

void foo( reference< const int > const x ) { (void) x; }        // OK

template< class Type >
void foot( reference< const Type > arg ) { (void) arg; }

void foot_call() { foot( 3.14 ); }      // Deduces arg type no problem.

void foo2( int const& const x ) { (void) x; }                   // !
```

With both Visual C++ and g++ this code compiles as indicated in the comments, with only `foo2` provoking a compilation error.

I would have liked `foo` to similarly result in compilation error, in order to be able to use that notation with the same constraints as the core language's “failed experiment” operator notation.

I suspect that the reason that `foo` compiles is the same as the reason why the call in `constref_call` compiles, some exemption to do with templates, but is that really so – what are the standard's formal rules here?

Comment: Rule is  [dcl.ref]/p1 "Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
through the use of a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers
are ignored."

Comment: In English: References are always const. You can't change them like pointers.

Comment: `-Wignored-qualifiers` works for `clang`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting C++11, 8.3.2/1:

> ... Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers
>   are ignored. ...

Comment: Thanks. Apparently this means that there's no way to guarantee a diagnostic?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Since the program is well-formed, I'd say there is indeed no such way.